# Save a file to a string within a specific thread

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am trying to save a text file into a string in C within a thread but I keep getting a segmentation fault. This is occuring within the instance of a thread being created. I have not worked with threads before so I'm not sure if that is contributing to the problem.

```
int getCurrentSegmentWordcount(int segment) { //declaring file pointer (value?)
    printf("func\n");
    char text[1000];
    char buffer[150];
    FILE *fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("null file");
    }
    int i = 0;
    // while(feof(fp)) {
    //  text[i++] = fgetc(fp);
    // }
    // text[i] = '\0'; //set null char to end string

    while(fgets(buffer, 150, fp)) {
        strcpy(text[i], buffer);
        printf("\n\n %s \n\n", text[i]);
        i++;
    }
    getchar();

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Below are my compiler warnings. There are no errors but multiple warnings.

```
assign2.c: In function ‘print_hello_world’:
assign2.c:10:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘void *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("Hello World. Greetings from thread %d\n", tid);
         ^
assign2.c: In function ‘getCurrentSegmentWordcount’:
assign2.c:29:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   strcpy(text[i], buffer);
          ^
In file included from assign2.c:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:125:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^
assign2.c:30:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("\n\n %s \n\n", text[i]);
          ^
assign2.c: In function ‘main’:
assign2.c:46:77: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, getCurrentSegmentWordcount(i), (void * )i);
                                                                             ^
assign2.c:46:46: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, getCurrentSegmentWordcount(i), (void * )i);
                                              ^
In file included from assign2.c:1:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:233:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
            ^
assign2.c:52:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘exit’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  exit(NULL);
       ^
In file included from assign2.c:3:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:543:13: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type 

‘void *’
     extern void exit (int __status) __THROW __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
./assign2exec
Main here. Creating thread 0
func
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: In this statement "strcpy(text[i], buffer);" what is "text[i]"...??  What does it need to be???  Also, is "i++" the correct thing to do..??

Comment: What are your compiler warnings telling you?

Comment: text[i] is the current char in the string text. i believe i++ is correct, because we have to move to the next char.

my compiler says segmentation fault

Comment: Check the "man" page on "strcpy()"... what is the type of its first argument? You did get a compiler warning about it ... the warning line begins with "assign2.c:29:10:"     (BTW these are hints to help you find the answer without someone telling you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you have to do, is to read the compiler warnings, not ignore
them. They are there to give you hints of what you are doing wrong, they are not
there to annoy you.

The function `strcpy` has this signature:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

From here it is clear that it expects `dest` to be a pointer to an `char` array
where the string pointed to by `src` will be saved.

You declared `char buffer[150];` so `buffer` is an `char` array, `buffer[i]`
will return a single `char`. So you are passing the incorrect type to `strcpy`.

The compiler is telling you this:

```
assign2.c: In function ‘getCurrentSegmentWordcount’:
assign2.c:29:10: warning: **passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast** [-Wint-conversion]
   strcpy(text[i], buffer);
```

You will need to have a 2 dimensional `char` array or an array of `char` pointer
in order to save this. The first one is the easiest to write:

```
char text[1000][1000];
```

The only problem is it has a fixed length on the number of lines, if the file has
more than 1000 lines, you cannot store all of them in the buffer.

The second option is the more robust:

```
int getCurrentSegmentWordcount(int segment) {
    char (*text)[1000] = NULL, char (*tmp)[1000];

    ...
    i = 0;
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp)) {

        // removing possible \n from buffer, you probably
        // want that
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;

        tmp = realloc(text, (i+1) * sizeof *tmp);
        if(tmp == NULL)
        {
            // error, cannot continue
            free(text);
            return;
        }

        text = tmp;
        strcpy(text[i], buffer);
        printf("\n\n %s \n\n", text[i]);
        i++;
    }
    ...

    free(text); // freeing the memory
}
```

And this version even more, it handles lines of different lengths

```
int getCurrentSegmentWordcount(int segment) {
    char **text = NULL, **tmp;

    ...
    i = 0;
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp)) {

        // removing possible \n from buffer, you probably
        // want that
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;

        tmp = realloc(text, (i+1) * sizeof *tmp);
        if(tmp == NULL)
        {
            // error, cannot continue
            free(text);
            return;
        }

        text = tmp;

        text[i] = calloc(strlen(buffer) + 1, 1);

        if(text[i] == NULL)
        {
            // error, free all the allocated memory:
            for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                free(text[j]);

            free(text);

            return;

        }

        strcpy(text[i], buffer);
        printf("\n\n %s \n\n", text[i]);
        i++;
    }
    ...

    // freeing the memory
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++i)
        free(text[i]);

    free(text);
}
```

I don't know if it is just your example, but your function is kind of pointless.
You store the lines in a buffer but don't do anything with it at all. This
function would be more productive if you've returned `text` or do something with
it.

The compiler warnings and errors show you all the lines where you have to
improve your code. One interesting line is:

```
assign2.c:52:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘exit’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  exit(NULL);
```

The correct call is

```
exit(0);
```